# Export PPT as mp4 or mov in PowerPoint

Tags: macos, ms-office, video

I want to export my presentation as video. Followed this: [Save a presentation as a movie file or MP4](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Save-a-presentation-as-a-movie-file-or-MP4-4e1ebcc1-f46b-47b6-922a-bac76c4a5691).

But I can't find any video formats in the Export menu.

[image: PowerPoint Export options]

Should I install any extension separately to have this work? Is there any other software which does conversion of presentations to video with all transitions and animations.

P.S: I use PowerPoint for Mac Version 15.34 [Office 2016].

Comment: I believe @patrix has the answer.  Looking at the "About Powerpoint" window, mine says `Version 15.33 License: Office 365 Subscription`  I have the ability to export to MOV, MP4, etc on a plain vanilla install.

Comment: @Allan Though I had Office 365 Subscription, the About Powerpoint window didn't have the words you mentioned except Version. Disabling and Enabling the license helped me link the License properly. Works fine now.

Comment: Upvoted the answer - I was aware that the O365 version was slightly different than the 2016 version, but I didn't know that a simple tweak of a plist would be the factor.  Great work!  I'm adding this to my notes for future reference!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry to answer this question myself. I had commented on a [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/powerpoint/comments/5vjnnu/powerpoint_2016_mac_export_video_missing/) in Reddit who had a similar issue, and thanks to atomicshed, he linked me to another [thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-mso_mac/the-export-to-video-file-format-is-missing-for-mac/8db74d02-2030-4c21-9645-5d610c85e979) at Microsoft's site.

This solution worked for me:

> Quit all Office 2016 apps
>
> Rename the file /Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.office.licensingV2.plist to something else
>
> Open any Office 2016 application, and sign in again to Activate the Subscription.

[image: Export Menu]

Now am able to export it as both MP4 and MOV. Thank you guys!

Comment: Answering your own question is not only allowed, but explicitly encouraged.  https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ Thanks for following up!

Answer (score 2):

From the site you've linked to:

> NOTE: This feature is only available to Office 365 subscribers. If you have an Office 365 subscription, make sure you have the latest version of Office.

Comment: Yes, I do have a Office 365 subscription: https://i.imgur.com/MrCz2RA.png. This issue is so weird.

Comment: What a weird thing to lock behind a subscription. For anyone who doesn't have Office 365, consider just using Quicktime Player to record the screen. Not quite as painless, but still a fairly quick process vs buying a subscription.

Comment: Yes, that's a better option.